# Using VPN connection and Firewall on Windows OS together in sequenced manner (for Local Network)

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, firewall

I am designing a Local Network where part of network is far away and connected to main network via Fiber Optic connection. On Main Network, I have a Win11 OS based machines which need to forward traffic to Server machine (no domain) for Log collection only. For security, I am planning to use IPSec VPN and Firewall and guaging if it is better to configure both natively on Host machine or use external Next-Gen Firewall for this purpose.

**I have questions related to idea if both VPN and Firewalls are configured on Windows**,

1. Are the firewall rules apply first on Inbound/outbound traffic before VPN tunnelling takes place or other way around?
2. Is there any possibility/option/configuration on Windows OS that allow Firewall to filter the outbound traffic first and then packets are sent on establish VPN tunnel; for inbound traffic to pass to VPN tunnel first and then gets filtered by Firewall.

Network Schema:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The firewall knows nothing about your VPN. All it does is allow or block
packages of data. The encrypting/decrypting of the data is done by the
VPN server and clients.

For your first question then, the answer is  that
firewall rules apply first on inbound/outbound traffic
before VPN tunnelling.

For your second question, it is unclear - please supply more details.

Comment: Hi @harrymc
Regarding second question, I want to make sure that from Host Machine point of view, sequence to be followed like this;
Outbound Traffic: Host App Data -> Firewall Filter-> VPN Encryption
Inbound Traffic: VPN Decryption -> Firewall Filter -> Host App

Comment: I may be misunderstanding : Do you mean a loop from the computer to itself? It might be better to add a schema of this circuit to your post.

Comment: Added the schema [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhy3V.png)

Comment: If I'm not still misunderstanding, this seems like a normal circuit where VPM packets are sent in each direction through two firewalls (client & server).

Comment: Actually, my impression from information I read on internet is that Windows Firewall first do filtering then VPN packets decrypts.

Comment: The Windows Firewall does no decryption of VPN packets. The VPN server and client are many times third-party products that are not part of Windows.

Comment: I am aware that Windows Firewall will not decrypt the VPN packet but does it filter on VPN encrypted packet or decrypted packet?

Comment: No, it doesn't do anything special for VPN. For the firewall this data is just bytes, as are all package payloads.